# merge [unix-sockets] and [unix-domain-sockets]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[unix-socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unix-socket) (123 Questions) and [unix-domain-sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unix-domain-sockets) (78) refer to the same thing.

Comment: Do you have a preference of which tag to use? I would go with [tag:unix-domain-sockets] after a quick look-over, but it's not my tag.

Comment: I have the same preference as you.

Comment: I had [asked the same](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142951/188688) before MSO and MSE got split. The counts have gone up quite a bit since I first asked this. I'd go with the shorter and more-often-used name, since I see no great danger of ambiguity.